Deriving a Langevin Equation for a Slow Variable in a Coupled Slow-Fast System
I'm working with a physical system composed of "slow" and "fast" variables, $ X $ and $ x $, with the Hamiltonian:
$$
H = H^s(X, P) + H^c(X, x) + H^f(x, p),
$$
where $ H^s $ represents the Hamiltonian for the slow subsystem, $ H^f $ for the fast subsystem, and $ H^c $ is a coupling energy between the two. For the slow variable, the equation of motion is:
$$
M \ddot{X} = -\frac{\partial H^c(X, x)}{\partial X}.
$$
I would be curious to consider a generic coupling Hamiltonian $ H^c(X, x, P, p) $, but for now, let’s assume $ H^c(X, x) $ depends only on $ X $ and $ x $ for simplicity.
I’m interested in deriving an underdamped Langevin-type equation for $ X $, assuming the fast subsystem (described by $ x $ and $ p $) remains in thermal equilibrium at a fixed value of $ X $.
My approach so far:

I consider the distribution of the force $ F = -\frac{\partial H^c(X, x)}{\partial X} $ as a random variable.
I calculate the mean and variance of this force, $ \langle F \rangle(X) $ and $ \langle F^2 \rangle(X) $, over the equilibrium distribution of the fast subsystem.
I assume the force distribution can be approximated as Gaussian, giving an effective Langevin equation:
$$
   M \ddot{X} = \langle F \rangle(X) + \sigma(X) \, \frac{dW}{dt},
   $$
where $ W $ is a Wiener process and $ \sigma(X) \sim \sqrt{\langle F^2 \rangle(X) - \langle F \rangle(X)^2} $ defines the noise amplitude.

How can I formally connect the noise term $\sigma(X)$ to the variance of the force?
Should there be an explicit damping term in the Langevin equation or can I avoid it? I know that you can use a damping term like $-\gamma\dot{X}$ and tune the combination of $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ to satisfy the fluctuation-dissipation theorem, but I wonder if this also applies if the slow system is far from equilibrium while only the fast one is.
Any insights or references would be appreciated!

Yes integrating fast degrees of freedom will lead to damping with memory. If you start from an hamiltonian dynamics, you WILL respect the fluctuation dissipation theorem. You can be out of equilibrium in the sense that you start with xeird initial condition but still  your noise must respect the FDT. And you must have damping such that the relaxation brings you toward the steady state. The formal derivation on this kind of thing is the Mori-Zwanzig formalism (I guess you probably know already).

Actually I am not aware of this formalism. Where can I read more about it?

AH my bad! Then it's nice that you found all these things by yourself. You're somewhat close to these ideas. I don't really have any source on this. I think you can write down "mori zwanzig/projection operator in statistical mechanics" and any source would do. A simple example of such elimination of fast variable is given in sec. 1.2.1.3 of  p.28 of the book Stochastic Enrrgetics by Ken Sekimoto. It's not general but it gives you a great idea of what the formalism does.
